# Danger on Using Supervisor Password / BIOS Password

Tags: bios, passwords

I would like to ask about the supervisor or most commonly known as BIOS password, my former instructor says that settings up that kind of password is harmful, and may cause corruption of BIOS in long run. I've search through Google about this matter but unfortunately I didnt find any result.

Comment: We had a bios get scrambled once due to a MB battery issue, reason unknown, the password wouldn't work either.

Comment: Every motherboard I have seen has jumpers.  Unplug computer, and short the reset pins and the password is cleared and your back in business.

Comment: Oh, is that so? But how about the laptops? I think it is difficult to remove the jumpers. Does laptop have jumpers also?

Comment: sounds like faulty information to me......

Comment: @mdpc, yeah you are right. That's why I ask it here to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corruption of BIOS? Ask him where did he see that, I've never heard of it!

Setting a BIOS password is never "harmful". It may be a problem if you forget it, or if you give/sell the computer to someone else and forget to tell them the password, but even that is usually reversible. Any real case of corruption is a serious bug in the BIOS, and should be an exception, not the rule.

I am actually in favor of setting the BIOS password, and I find it sketchy that someone would recommend against it. It may be the case that they want to guarantee access to your computer (by, unbeknownst to you, changing the BIOS options to allow booting from a live CD/pen). But this is already me in paranoid mode :-)

Comment: Oh, maybe you are right. He just want to access my computer. :) Thanks! So meaning to say searching for a corrupted BIOS will lead me nowhere because it does not exist? Haha!

Comment: It may exist, but it certainly won't happen just because you set a password. Especially not "in the long run", as if that would happen over time.
Also, since my answer was the one you accepted, please upvote it too, if you have the rep to do it :)

Comment: Thanks, right now I cant vote you up. I think 15 reputation is required to do that. Maybe you can vote me up. :) Haha!